# sqlite select query for last 24hrs

Tags: linux, sqlite

Can we perform sqlite select query for last 24hrs only by time validation,not by using date & time.

My pc time is ""2013-05-23 22:30:00",below are my records i have in my sqlite db.

```
S.no        Time   
-------------------------------
001         2013-05-22 22:00:10    
002         2013-05-22 22:15:10    
003         2013-05-22 22:30:00    
004         2013-05-23 01:10:10    
005         2013-05-23 10:10:13    
006         2013-05-23 22:30:00
```

**After performing 24hrs time query can I get the following row data something like this?**

Expected result:

```
S.no        Time   
------------------------------- 
004         2013-05-23 01:10:10    
005         2013-05-23 10:10:13    
006         2013-05-23 22:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM WhateverTheTableIsNamed
WHERE Time > datetime('now', 'localtime', '-1 days')
```